# Sublime Text breaks after tree view refreshment and requires an OS reboot to work again (Linux)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, archlinux, package-control

I'm currently struggling with a bug(?), which completely breaks Sublime after some time of using it and requires a complete OS reboot to make it work again. The only correlation I found so far is that this always happens whenever a tree view refreshment is triggered (either manually or by creating or deleting a file or directory). Though, it also happened once when I hit tabulator for auto completion, so I'm not quite sure.

The first time this happened was after I opened a very large SQL file by mistake and killed the process, because, you know, Sublime and large files.

I already tried deleting the session files, but that didn't change anything.

I have absolutely no idea what this could be about, so I'd be very thankful for *any* kind of ideas, that could lead to the right direction.

---

**Operating System:** Arch Linux. Maybe that's of some relevance, I don't know. I'm using the [official stable channel for pacman](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#pacman), though.

**Package Control / Packages:** A File Icon, AdvancedNewFile, Alignment, All Autocomplete, Autoprefixer, Case Conversion, CodeFormatter, Color Highlighter, CSScomb, DocBlockr, Emmet, FileDiffs, Git, GitGutter, Grunt, HTML-CSS-JS Prettify, Inc-Dec-Value, jQuery, Less, Local History, MarkdownEditing, Material Theme, Package Control, PHP-Twig, PyV8, Sass, SFTP, SideBarEnhancements, SQLTools, SublimeCodeIntel, SublimeLinter, SublimeLinter-php, Sublimerge 3, Symfony2 Snippes, Terminal, Xdebug Client, zzz A File Icon zzz

**Settings:**

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",
    "dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic",
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_options":
    [
        "gray_antialias"
    ],
    "font_size": 10,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Markdown",
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
    "material_theme_bright_scrollbars": true,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "remember_full_screen": true,
    "rulers":
    [
        80,
        120
    ],
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
}
```

Comment: could it maybe be related to the number of inotify handles ST uses? https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1195

Comment: Nothing suspicious there. My Sublime uses about five inotify handles in average, even while working in my whole project folder. It also doesn't change after triggering a tree view refreshment.